# i want to use modal but i just keep on getting $(...).modal is not a function. I have used jquery and bootstrap js in proper order

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

my imports for modal are

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../resources/js/checkbox_hide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and i am calling it as..

```
function showPandLModal(){
    $('#vehiclePandLModal').modal('toggle');
};
```

i am making some small error but unable to find it.

Comment: Check this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: i have removed  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> and checked rest of the page worked but still getting (...).modal is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Add this too:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: still getting same error after using above solution.

Answer (score 0):

i used "js" imports from other page where modal was working. It worked but i am still not sure about what imports are needed for modal. Any Explanation is welcomed.